# Save geocoder coordinates using async/await pre-save in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to save this coordinates in mongodb, can someone help me ?

```
  UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next) {
                  const doc = this
                  const geo = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
                  this.lat = geo
                 //here when I console log it shows undefined
                  console.log(this.lat)
               //but here it shows the geocoder's response 
                  console.log(geo)
   })
```

what can it be ? someone can help me ?

here is the console.logs response

```
 undefined
 [
   {
     latitude: -2.4454537,
     longitude: -54.7186729,
     formattedAddress: 'Avenida Jasmin, Santarém, Microrregião de Santarém, 
     Região Geográfica Intermediária de Santarém, Pará, Região Norte, 
     68020-280, 
      Brasil',
     country: 'Brasil',
     city: 'Santarém',
     state: 'Pará',
     zipcode: '68020-280',
     streetName: 'Avenida Jasmin',
     streetNumber: undefined,
     countryCode: 'BR',
     neighbourhood: '',
     provider: 'openstreetmap'
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I admit there was a very silly way to solve this, I just created a array in the UserScheme

```
  const UserScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
coords:[
    

    
],
)}
```

and then :

```
 UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next) {
     const geo = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
     console.log(geo)
     this.coords = geo
  })
```

ok, easily solved